# jQuery UI Sortables - can't access new list item that I drag over

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Using WordPress and working with Widgets.  When I drag over a new widget to the sidebar (dragging over a list item from one sortable area to another)... I'm trying to bind the `sortreceive` event so that I can apply some new rules to the elements within that new widget.  But I'm not able to access that new list item and apply some event handlers.

```
$('div.widgets-sortables').bind( 'sortreceive', findToggles );

function findToggles(){
    var featuredPostsWidget = $( 'div[id*="my_featured_posts-widget"]' );
    console.log(featuredPostsWidget);
}
```

When I `console.log()` each widget that exists on the page, I see all the old ones but not the new one I just dragged over.  If I drag over another widget to the sidebar, it'll now log the previous one I just dragged over, but not the new one.

The `sortreceive` event seems to be firing just fine, but I can't search for elements inside the new list item.

Any idea on how I can apply some event handlers to the new list item?